# How to call Parent class function inside child class in javascript

Tags: javascript

Here is my code
I have two class
1. ledger with having one function first().
2. supplier without function.

Now i want to call first() function inside supplier class.

https://gyazo.com/bea7ef497b58d390e279d3e2ea668431

```
var ledger = function(){};
ledger.prototype = {

    first   : function(){
        alert('first function is being called!');
    }
} // END OF ledger CLASS

var supplier = function(){}
supplier.prototype = {

    first();

} // END OF supplier CLASS

jQuery(function(){

    // INHERITANCE 
    supplier.prototype = create.Object(ledger.prototype);

});
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: 99% of questions posted are required to have a [mcve]
Please post JavaScript/jQuery, CSS, and HTML that would be relevant to your question. Create a demo using any or all of the following services: 
[Plunker.co](http://plnkr.co/), 
[jsFiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/), 
[CodePen.io](https://codepen.io/),  
[JS Bin](https://jsbin.com/)
or a snippet (7th icon located on the text editor toolbar or CTRL+M).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var Ledger = function() {};

Ledger.prototype.first = function () {
    console.log("First!");
};

var Supplier = function () {
    Ledger.call(this);
};

Supplier.prototype = Object.create(Ledger.prototype);
Supplier.prototype.constructor = Supplier;

Supplier.prototype.second = function () {
  console.log("Second!");
  this.first();
};

var supplier = new Supplier();

// First!
supplier.first();

// Second!
// First!
supplier.second();

console.log(supplier instanceof Ledger);   // true 
console.log(supplier instanceof Supplier); // true
```

Comment: @Vipin Yes. First, you can't assign an object to `prototype` or you will override the prior content. If you still wanna do so, you can use `Object.assign()` to keep the prior content. Second, you have to implement the `second()` method after the `Object.create()` call. I have changed your code and now it works. Take a look: https://jsfiddle.net/LLczxj8L/

Comment: To be honest, I am completely lost now.
My mind is not able to make a map of all this story yet. Nevertheless, i want to learn this because i enjoy OOP's.
Can you please send some sort of document or url where i can read about all this?
Looking forward to hear from you soon.
Cheers!

Comment: @Vipin The Mozilla Developer Network is a good source. Take a look at this document: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript

Comment: @Vipin Also, if the new ECMAScript 6, that includes JavaScript classes (not supported by all browsers yet), is an option for you, take a look at this one: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes